# Trying to recreate the .isFunction() from the jQuery source

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, design-patterns

I'm trying to learn some thing from jQuery source by breaking some pieces apart. Right now I'm going over the `isFunction`. In my code `test` is instead of `jQuery`. The problem is that `isFunction` is telling me that `stub` is not a function by outputting false `stub` is a function.

I noticed that jquery doesn't use the `this` in  `return this.type(obj) === "function"` like in my code and instead of writing the code in `test.prototype ={`,  jQuery writes it in `jQuery.extend({` maybe that's my problem? I didnt include extend function.

Try to keep the answer like jQuery's source code structure I know my code is a little different.

Also, Do you know of a smaller library like jQuery that I could use to learn from? I don't need to learn about AJAX and promises right now I just want to learn about structure of code and DOM manipulation.There's so much information in jQuery.

```
var test = function(){

}
var class2type = {};
test.prototype ={
    type : function(obj){
        if(obj == null){
            return obj + "";
        }
        return typeof obj === "object" || typeof obj === "function" ?
                    class2type[ toString.call(obj) ] || "object" :
                    typeof obj;
    },
    isFunction :function(obj){
        return this.type(obj) === "function"
    }
}


var stub = function stub(){}
console.log(typeof stub)
console.log(test.prototype.isFunction(stub))
```

Comment: If you want to learn from other libraries, lodash is an amazing utility library with great code quality and documentation (doesn't include DOM manipulation though).

Comment: Your `class2type` map is empty. jQuery's isn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the declaration for `class2type`. Basically, what's happening is that `class2type[toString.call(obj)]` is returning `undefined`, so `test.prototype.type(stub)` returns `"object"`, which is not equal to `"function"`, so `test.prototype.isFunction(stub)` returns `false`.

To fix it, add this to `class2type`:

```
class2type = {
  '[object Function]': 'function'
};
```

Comment: I see what your talking about. Thanks. I'm trying to reproduce when you would get `[object Function]`  I think I saw `[object object]` before but I forgot how to produce that in the console or alert . can you show me?
Edit `typeof stub` produces `function` not `[object Function]`

Comment: `console.log(toString.call(function() {}));`

Comment: Thanks for your answer I see that it works, but what exactly is going on here. I'm confused. I know the first arg of call is the `this` or the object that  you want something applied to. so why doesn't `(function() {}).toString()` work?  it looks that's similar to what you did. Thanks in advance

Comment: `toString` and `Function.toString` are not the same. When you use `toString`, it's using the global object's `toString` (in the case of the browser, `window.toString`). `Function.toString` overrides `Object.toString` with a different implementation, that's why you get different results and that's why `(function() {}).toString()` doesn't work in this case.

Comment: @FelipeBrahm: I'm pretty sure actually that jQuery uses `var toString = Object.prototype.toString;`, not the global "variable".

Comment: @Bergi this is not jQuery. This is an example outside of jQuery. When referencing `toString` in any environment, it will fall back to the global `toString` unless there's another local variable with the same name. In the case of the browser, it will use `window.toString`, which inherits from `Object.prototype.toString`.

Comment: @FelipeBrahm: All I'm saying is that [there *is* such a local variable in jQuery](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.11.3/dist/jquery.js#L58) (although they use something like `{}.toString` to create it, not an `Object.prototype` reference).